# Xamarin ExpandableListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, mobile, xamarin

Is there anything like this native in Xamarin? Something where there is a list of parent elements, and when one of them is clicked on a list of child elements appears under it.

Ex.

```
Parent
 -Child
 -Child
Parent
Parent
```

I tried putting a custom:listview inside a custom:listview. The plan was to change visibility on click, but I get the following error:

System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ListViewAdapter from native handle 0xbf835bfc (key_handle 0x26566218).

Comment: Are you using Android, iOS, or Xamarin Forms?  You can do this in Android, but not in iOS or Forms without writing custom controls.

Comment: @Jason I'm using Xamarin Forms.

Comment: You can't do it natively in Forms, because there is no native control in iOS for it to map to.  You can either write a custom control, or write a custom renderer.  There are many discussions out there regarding this issue; or see this: https://github.com/danvanderboom/Xamarin-Forms-TreeView

Comment: @Jason If you want to put this as an answer I can mark it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this natively in Xamarin Forms using Grouping headers in a ListView. First create a Grouping structure:

```
public class Grouping<TK, T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public TK Key { get; private set; }

    public Grouping(TK key, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        Key = key;
        foreach (var item in items)
            Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Create a ViewModel to wrap your Parent Model with an extra boolean property to signify that the parent has been selected/should display its child items:

```
public class SelectParentViewModel
{
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

In your page's ViewModel create the following property to Bind to your ListView

```
public ObservableCollection<Grouping<SelectParentViewModel, Child>> Parents { get; set; }
```

Initlialise Parents to contain a new Grouping for each of your parents with a new empty list for the Child elements.

Add a Command which takes a `Grouping<SelectCategoryViewModel, Item>` as a parameter. The Command first flips the Selected property of the Grouping's Key. It then checks the new value of the Selected property:

- If true -> Populates the Child elements
- If false -> Clears the Child elements

In your ListView

- Bind the ItemsSource property to the Categories property and set IsGroupingEnabled to "True"
- Set the ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate to a ViewCell to display each Parent
- Add a tapped gesture recognizer to the outer view in the ViewCell which calls the command to either clear or populate the child Items for the parent
- Set the ListView.ItemTemplate to display each child element

This blog post describes Grouping in Listviews:
http://motzcod.es/post/94643411707/enhancing-xamarinforms-listview-with-grouping

An example Forms project demonstrating this is available on my GitHub
https://github.com/umarmohammed/XFExpandableListView

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem and used a Custom Control to get it working.

If you create an 'ExpandableView' Content View with Xaml like:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="MyProject.CustomControls.ExpandableView">
    <StackLayout  x:Name="Layout" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout x:Name="SummaryRegion">               
        <StackLayout x:Name="DetailsRegion"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

And wire up the .cs class like so:

```
   public partial class ExpandableView: ContentView
    {

        private TapGestureRecognizer _tapRecogniser;
        private StackLayout _summary;
        private StackLayout _details;

        public ExpandableView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeGuestureRecognizer();
            SubscribeToGuestureHandler();    
        }

        private void InitializeGuestureRecognizer()
        {
            _tapRecogniser= new TapGestureRecognizer();
            SummaryRegion.GestureRecognizers.Add(_tapRecogniser);
        }

        private void SubscribeToGuestureHandler()
        {
            _tapRecogniser.Tapped += TapRecogniser_Tapped;
        }

        public virtual StackLayout Summary
        {
            get { return _summary; }
            set
            {
                _summary = value;    
                SummaryRegion.Children.Add(_summary);
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public virtual StackLayout Details
        {
           get { return _details; }
           set 
           {
              _details = value;
              DetailsRegion.Children.Add(_details);
              OnPropertyChanged();
           }
       }

       private void TapRecogniser_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DetailsRegion.IsVisible)
        {
            DetailsRegion.IsVisible = false;
        }
        else
        {
             DetailsRegion.IsVisible = true;
        }
    }
```

And then on your page wrap something like this in a list view:

```
<CustomControls:ExpandableView>
   <CustomControls:ExpandableView.Summary>
       <StackLayout>
          YOUR PARENT HERE 
       </StackLayout>
   </CustomControls:ExpandableView.Summary>
   <CustomControls:ExpandableView.Details>
        <StackLayout>
          YOUR CHILD LIST VIEW HERE
        </StackLayout>
    </CustomControls:ExpandableView.Details>
 </CustomControls:ExpandableView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this TreeView a go:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Adapt.Presentation/tree/master/Adapt.Presentation.Standard/Adapt/Presentation/Controls/TreeView

It's very simple. No custom rendering.

You can clone the repo with a sample here:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Adapt.Presentation.git